# Google cloud Security Command Center doesn't allow me to enter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, securitycenter

I am trying to enter the Google cloud platform "Security Command Center", but although I am logged in as the Super Admin / Owner, it presents this error:

[image: Error message]

It has been working before, so I wonder if I have touched something e.g. disabled the Security Center altogether, but I don't think so.

Edit: I have applied the additional role "Security Centre Admin" to no avail:
[image]

The user I am using is the owner of the organization (ok not the best of ideas to use a root account but if not even this user can get access..)

Grateful for any input.

Comment: Are you part of an Organization? The error lists the permissions you need. Do you have them? If not add them. Note: Project Owner does not have all permissions by default. For some, you must manually add them. Edit your question with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the securitycenter permission granted on your super admin user, and at the organization level.

The roles are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/access-control). I recommend you one of this 3:

- roles/securitycenter.admin
- roles/securitycenter.adminEditor
- roles/securitycenter.adminViewer

Comment: Thanks Guillaume, I have edited my post, seems like the user now should have the Admin role but still I get the same error..

Comment: OK, you need to have all of those roles applied, although the "Owner" role gives you "access to all resources", these roles are explicitly needed (all the 3 of them) for Command center to run. So your reply is the solution.